# how to set CupertinoSegmentedControl height?

Tags: dart, flutter, segmentedcontrol

I am trying to use `CupertinoSegmentedControl` from the flutter *Cupertino library* in the `AppBar` using the bottom attribute to achieve the following design (height = 32)

[image: cupertino segmented control]

so I tried the following :

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    elevation: 2,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: Text(this.widget.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const  EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 12),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 24),
              Expanded(
                child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                  children: this.widget.tabs,
                  groupValue: this._selectedTab,
                  onValueChanged: (value) {
                    this.setState(() => this._selectedTab = value);
                    this._tabController.animateTo(value);
                  }
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 24)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 48)
      )
                ),
                body: new TabBarView(
                    controller: this._tabController,
                    children: this.widget.views,
                ));
    }
```

Comment: Look at my answer. I don't know if did understand what you actually want, If it's not of any help, I'm going to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is something like that similar to the layout that you want? (Removing the green color of course ^_^)

Play around with the `Container` and `PreferredSize` *heights* to adjust the height to fit your needs.

[image]

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title:
            Text(this.widget.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 48,
                    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                    child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                        children: children,
                        groupValue: this._selectedTab,
                        onValueChanged: (value) {
                          this.setState(() => this._selectedTab = value);
                        }),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 48))),
    body: Center(
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('hello')
        ]
        )
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**:

[image]

As kazimad pointed out, if you want to increase the segmented control height and not only add padding to it insiede the app bar, you can add a `Padding` widget to your tabs, like that:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          centerTitle: true,
          title:
              Text(this.widget.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 12),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 24),
                    Expanded(
                      child: CupertinoSegmentedControl(
                          children: const <int, Widget>{
                            0: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text('Midnight')),
                            1: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text('Viridian')),
                            2: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Text('Cerulean'))
                          },
                          groupValue: this._selectedTab,
                          onValueChanged: (value) {
                            // TODO: - fix it
                          }),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 24)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 48))),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [Text('hello')])));
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work. CupertinoSegmentedControl doesn't expands it's height

Comment: @kazimad You're right. I've totally forgot this answer, but reding it again I realized what the OP really asked. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

just add Padding widget, or margin property to Container and wrap your Widgets in your "tabs" collection (in you case it is this.widget.tabs) with it

in my case

```dart
CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
            children: segmentTextWidgets,
            ...
          ),


final Map<int, Widget> segmentTextWidgets = <int, Widget>{
    0: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      child: Text("Tab 1 title"),
    ),
    1: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
      child: Text("Tab 2 title"),
    ),
  };
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you could improve it with a minimal functioning sample code and images so that it's more educational for the future readers.